# Show that $A$ is dense iff $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A) = \emptyset$.

Tags: real-analysis

Please I need help for this question.
Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $X$. Show that $A$ is dense iff $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A) = \emptyset$.
I don't know how to relate denseness with interior.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A key idea is $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A) = X \setminus \bar{A}$. With this, we find that $A$ is dense in $X$ $\iff$ $\overline{A} = X$ $\iff$ $X \setminus \bar{A} = \emptyset$ $\iff$ $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A) = \emptyset$.